# C# compare 2 files substrings for matches

Tags: c#

I am trying to find a way to compare some text in 2 files and if a match is found .

Here are examples of the files;

'File A'

ex1,TEXAS,24

ex2,MIAMI,78

ex3,ATLANTA,56

ex4,NY,90

...

'File B'

ex1,JHON,1110

exA,DAVID,1060

exB,CATHY,230

ex4,ROBERT,1200

...

Using my 2 example files, I want to search them both and find matches(

ex1,TEXAS,24

&

ex4,NY,90

)??!

Here is my try

```
private void button4_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string fileA, fileB, fileC;
        fileA = textBox1.Text;
        fileB = textBox2.Text;
        fileC = "result.txt";

        string alphaFilePath = fileA;

        List<string> alphaFileContent = new List<string>();
        using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(alphaFilePath, FileMode.Open))
        using (StreamReader rdr = new StreamReader(fs))
        {
            while (!rdr.EndOfStream)
            {
            }
        }
        string betaFilePath = fileB;

        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();


        using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(betaFilePath, FileMode.Open))
        using (StreamReader rdr = new StreamReader(fs))
        {
            while (!rdr.EndOfStream)
            {
                string[] betaFileLine = rdr.ReadLine().Split(Convert.ToChar(","));
              }
        }
        using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(fileC, FileMode.Create)){
    using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(fs))
    {
        writer.Write(sb.ToString());
    }
}               foreach (var item in alphaFileContent)
                {
                    if (item.StartsWith(betaFileLine[0]))
                    {
                        sb.AppendLine(String.Format("{0}", betaFileLine[0]));
                    }

                }


    }
```

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: Where's the code that exemplifies the difficulty you're having?

Comment: S.Petrosov plz take a look at my try

Comment: Marc.C plz take a look to my try

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get all the lines of a file into an array using `File.ReadAllLines`:

```
var alphaFileContents = File.ReadAllLines(fileA);
```

In your code, you are checking to see which items from file A `StartWith` the same text as an item from file B up to the first comma. We can get all the prefixes (line contents up to the first comma) from fileB by using `string.Split(',')[0]`, which splits the string into an array on the comma character, and then returns the first item (at index `0`):

```
var betaFilePrefixes = File.ReadAllLines(fileB).Select(line => line.Split(',')[0]);
```

Now, we can find the similar items by getting all items in fileA that start with an item from fileB. The `Where` clause below says, "where any `alpha` item starts with an item in `betaFilePrefixes`:

```
var similarItems = alphaFileContents
    .Where(alpha => betaFilePrefixes.Any(beta => alpha.StartsWith(beta)));
```

Then, you can write all the matching lines to the `results` file using `File.WriteAllLines`:

```
File.WriteAllLines(fileC, similarItems);
```

So, to put it all together, you can do this:

```
private void button4_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var fileA = textBox1.Text;
    var fileB = textBox2.Text;
    var fileC = "result.txt";

    // Read the alpha file contents into a list
    var alphaFileContents = File.ReadAllLines(fileA);

    // Read each line of the beta file, and select the first part
    // (up to the first comma) into a list
    var betaFilePrefixes = File.ReadAllLines(fileB).Select(line => line.Split(',')[0]);

    // Get all alpha lines that start with an item in the beta list
    var similarItems = alphaFileContents
        .Where(alpha => betaFilePrefixes.Any(alpha.StartsWith));

    // Write the lines to our result file
    File.WriteAllLines(fileC, similarItems);
}
```

Comment: thank you just wanna write the all line fileA for similarItems, how to do that?

Comment: Does this code not do what you want? And if not, what is not working?

Comment: it works just what i want is get the whole line for the matches instead of File.WriteAllText(fileC, string.Join(",", similarItems)); ==>File.WriteAllText(fileC, string.Join(",", linefileA));!! Any idea ?

Comment: It would be really helpful if you updated your question with actual examples. In the examples you give, FileA only has one line, and FileB only has one line, and your example output contains items that do not exist in FileB (like textA and intA) as well as the `&` character. Why not give a simple example of actual file contents (small amount) and what you are looking for in terms of output?

Comment: example2,textA,intA

Comment: Got it (I think)! I've update the answer, see if it makes sense.

Comment: woow great works like a charm thank youuuuuuuuuuuu @Rufus L

Answer (score 0):

```
var matches = File.ReadAllText(fileA).Split(',')
    .Intersect(File.ReadAllText(fileB).Split(','));
```

Comment: Thanks Yuriy i applied your code and got system.linq.Enumerable+<IntersectIterator>d__1'1[system.String] i used it link this var path1 ="C:/Users/.../fileA.txt";
             var path2 = "C:/Users/... /fileB.txt";

Comment: var matches = File.ReadAllText(path1).Split(',')
                .Intersect(File.ReadAllText(path2).Split(','));

Comment: @M.elsie if you want to print the results you can use `string.Join(",", matches)`

Comment: @Yuriy Faktorovich CompuChip than you just wanna ask how to get and print the whole line file A for elements matches? is it easy ti use readline instead of readalltext?